# Pass parameters to a query in chunks

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a postgres database, I am executing queries using sqlalchemy. Sometimes I am passing too many parameters to the query which is resulting in sequential scans. Sample query

```
session.query(orm.table.name, orm.table.age).filter(orm.table.id.in_(([1, 2, .......]).all()
```

To mitigate this issue,  I have decided to pass the parameters in chunks, .i.e passing 100 parameters at once.
One way is to modify all my queries to something like

```
all_results = []
for i in range(0, len(params), chunk_size):
    res = session.query(orm.table.name, orm.table.age).filter(orm.table.id.in_(params[i: i+ chunk_size)).all()
    all_results.append(res)
```

I have a lot of queries and using this method, I need to modify all of them. Is there are cleaner workaround or something sqlalchemy supports?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is you chunked version actually faster than doing a sequential scan in the database?

Comment: @JesseBakker the speed of the two approaches is comparable. I am mostly concerned about the IOPS consumption on aws rds. With more parameters, it is taking a very high hit on the IOPS consumption.